# PostMethod setRequestBody(String) deprecated - why?

Tags: java, request, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache Commons HttpClient PostMethod 3.1.

In the PostMethod class there are also three methods for setting POST method's request body:

```
setRequestBody(InputStream body)
setRequestBody(String body)
setRequestBody(NameValuePair[] parametersBody);
```

[NameValuePair](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/NameValuePair.html) API 
First two methods are deprecated. Does anybody knows why? Because if I want to put an XML to request body, NameValuePair does not help me.

Does anybody knows an workaround or a solution?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The javadoc says:

> Deprecated. use setRequestEntity(RequestEntity)

RequestEntity has a lot of implementors, namely:

> ByteArrayRequestEntity, FileRequestEntity, InputStreamRequestEntity, MultipartRequestEntity, StringRequestEntity

Use the one that suits you:

- if your xml is in a `String`, use the [`StringRequestEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/StringRequestEntity.html)
- if it is in a file, use the [`FileRequestEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/FileRequestEntity.html)

and so on.

Comment: `StringRequestEntity` not found in Suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, so for example,

```
post.setRequestEntity( new StringRequestEntity( xml ) );
```

instead of

```
post.setRequestBody( xml );
```

Comment: Unfortunately the constructor `StringRequestEntity(String)` is deprecated now too. Instead you'll have to use: `post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xml, "text/xml", "ISO-8859-1"));`